# When do I split my project to multiple C files? (good practices for large projects)

Tags: c, project

Im working on a big project in C right now, im doing a specific part of it (the other is done by others), I want to know when should my project be split into multiple c files, and what are the best practices for writing large projects, with a team (or alone).
My previous experience was with headers (having a header and a .c where all the functions were
written).

Comment: might be more relevant on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), e.g. "development methodologies" is listed as on-topic there

Comment: This question is most likely going to be closed very soon, but I wanted to remark that your team lead is hopefully able to answer such questions. It would be dangerous to jeopardize the success of the project by having people work on it (in C, not exactly the easiest language for writing correct programs) which are not experienced enough to make a judgement on this. I assume you have some project guidelines for this (along with a code style).

Answer (score 2):

People will tell you different things.  In general:

- You should split a file into smaller files if:

  - It has many dependencies
  - It takes too long to compile
  - It knows or does too much
- You should organize your project by:

  - Which parts work with which types of data
  - Which parts work with which other parts of the project
- Things you should avoid:

  - Headers which only work if included in specific orders
  - Headers which pull in large blobs of the project (too many dependencies)
  - Abuse of preprocessor macros
  - A "util.c" or similar. From personal experience, they tend to grow out of control

In C++ (not C), I tend to have a .h and .cpp file for each major class I write, and I may sometimes lump some supporting classes into files with other classes to which they are very closely related, and without which they are more or less meaningless (anecdotally, I have a medium project containing such classes as Scheduler and SchedulerEvent in the same file, in which a Scheduler holds a collection of SchedulerEvents.  The project has around 180 files and is still easy to maintain).

Comment: perhaps if a question will be closed so soon you shouldn't encourage people to ask it by answering it? to the upvoters - can i ask on what merit you are upvoting this answer?

Comment: @Claudiu: I find it ironic that a question with only upvotes and no downvotes, about how to design large projects, gets closed as "not constructive".  Don't you smell something funny about that?  For large projects ESPECIALLY, proper design is very important.  It's the difference between a bubble sort and a quicksort.

Comment: @Wug: the difference between bubble sort and quicksort is very specific and easily answerable (and note that bubble sort is better in some cases). this question was extremely open-ended, which is why it got closed, i think. these sorts of open-ended questions were welcomed on the early stackoverflow but it seems there's been a move away from that

Comment: Agree with you, Wug. I upvoted you, and the question, and voted to reopen. Sorry I don't have more votes.

Comment: @Claudiu: I see a very specific question (though I went on to answer a few others), regarding when to split a C file into seperate files.  There are objective reasons to do this, anyone who has managed a build process for a large project can tell you what they are off the top of their head.

Comment: @Wug: personally if he just asked the header splitting thing that would have been fine, but when I saw "and what are the best practices for writing large projects, with a team (or alone)" it got too open-ended for me

Comment: @DervinThunk: Thankfully, I ninja'd the close with my placeholder answer. :D

Comment: ah actually re-reeading it i guess he meant just in the context of header files. fine w/ me, i vote to reopen

Comment: I'll point out that the project may be academic, in which case the project lead may not know much more than he does.  Or maybe he is the project lead.  Who knows.

Comment: @Wug: the question is not specific at all; there are no details about the project itself, or how labor is being divided among the other programmers.  Yes, there are rules of thumb, but they may not apply in this situation.  We just don't know enough to provide more than very vague guidelines which may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, put a type definition (or closely depending type definitions) and the functions to handle such type(s) into one module.

Public type(s) and functions go into the `.h`-file, private type(s) and functions and all implementations go into the `.c`-file.

`.h`-files without `.c`-files are rare.

Comment: "`.h`-files without `.c`-files are rare."  Yep, I'd say so.  They tend to fit into one of two categories; the aggregate header file which serves no purpose but to include several others for convenience, and the #defined constant header file, which contains exclusively or almost exclusively preprocessor macros.